# How to categorize Outlook email using add-in?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin

I want to categorize or add a tag while sending an email in Outlook.

I have an [add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial) to add some `id` to the email content.

Can I add a tag to an email using the `id` or is there any way to categorize an email using an add-in?

[image]

As you can see the image, I can select and insert a matter(each matter has an `id` like 1, 2...).

But I don't want to add a matter just to the content, I want to add a tag or categorize with a matter to an email.

How to implement this?

Should I add extensions using graph api or is there any item to keep a tag in email data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either extended properties or open extensions for your scenario. If its extended properties then it allow storing custom data and specifically serve as a fallback mechanism for apps to access custom data for Outlook MAPI properties when these properties are not already exposed in the Microsoft Graph API metadata. You can get it [started from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).